# Python variable declarations

Tags: python, syntax

I came across this piece of code and am wondering what it means:

```
typ, dat = imap_conn.search(None, search_string)
```

What exactly does the `typ, dat` part of the line mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is tuple unpacking, see [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). If your function returns a tuple you can always unpack it using a syntax similar to `a, b = func()`.

Also, you can use tuples on the fly, like `a, b = b, a` can be used for swapping two values.

Comment: And swapping that way is actually _faster_ than swapping using a temporary value.

Answer (score 3):

`typ, dat` is a tuple. When used on the left hand side of an assignment `a, b = x` it is equivalent to:

```
a = x[0]
b = x[1]
```

In your example, `typ, dat = imap_conn.search(None, search_string)` is equivalent to:

```
search_res = imap_conn.search(None, search_string)
typ = search_res[0]
dat = search_res[1]
```

This technique of writing a tuple on the left hand side of an assignment is known as tuple unpacking.

Comment: @Jeff How can the assignment be done simultaneously? It will be done sequentially.

Comment: "Simultaneously" probably was the wrong word here.  I'm not sure what is exactly.  It was meant to be a comment on how swapping could be performed with this.

Comment: @Jeff I kind of know what you are driving at!

Comment: I think the "simultaneous" can only really mean that  (a) the assignments are commutative, and (b) the RHS is only evaluated once.  The second example has both these properties, the only difference is that it creates a temporary name.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can assign and/or return more than one value, as per the following code:

```
def fn ():
    return (7, 2)

(seven, two) = fn()
print seven
print two
print fn()
```

This outputs:

```
7
2
(7, 2)
```

I prefer the explicit tuple syntax (the one with the parentheses) myself since I believe it makes the intent clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
typ, dat = imap_conn.search(None, search_string)
```

The expression on right-hand side returns two values which are assigned to the two variables on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what search is returning. You can unpack a result using that syntax. So for example:

```
>>>x, y = (1,2)
>>>x
1
>>>y
2
>>> x, y =[(1,2), [1,2,3,(1,2)]]
>>> x
(1, 2)
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, (1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called "unpacking", i believe the `imap_conn.search(None, search_string` method returns 2 values (probably a tuple), this notation allows you can assign them to 2 variables in one shot.

This is equivalent to:

```
return_val = imap_conn.search(None, search_string)
typ = return_val[0]
dat = return_val[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for assignments is given at http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target          ::=  identifier
                     | "(" target_list ")"
                     | "[" target_list "]"
                     | attributeref
                     | subscription
                     | slicing
```

the left hand side of the assignment contains one or more `target_list` which are comma separate targets. A sequence on the right hand side is then unpacked into each target. Notice that the definition is recursive, so you can even do things like:

```
a, [b, c, [d, e]], f = 1, (2, 3, (4, 5)), 6
```

but at each level the number of elements and the nesting must match. If you are using Python 3 then there is an option to include `*target` in the target_list and that will swallow a variable number of arguments.